# Show that for exactly two positions of $A_1'$ the points $A_1'$ and $A_1''$ coincide

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

> Let $A_1, A_2, A_3$ be three distinct points on circle $S$. For any
> given point $A_1'$ on $S$, the points $A_2',A_3',A_1''$ are chosen on
> $S$ such that $A_1'A_2',A_2'A_3',A_3'A_1''$ are perpendicular to
> $A_1A_2,A_2A_3,A_3A_1$, respectively. Show that for exactly two
> positions of $A_1'$ the points $A_1'$ and $A_1''$ coincide

*This is the second part to a problem that I am working through. I have managed to complete the first part, but I will post it here as it may give you a hint as to how to solve this problem:*

> (a) The distinct points $L,M,P$ and $Q$ on the Argand diagram lie on a circle $S$ centred the origin and the corresponding complex numbers are $l,m,p$ and $q$. By considering the perpendicular bisectors of the chords, or otherwise, prove that the chord $LM$ is perpendicular to the chord $PQ$ if and only if $lm+pq=0$

I have tried several times to produce a sketch of this problem, but failed. I am guessing there are only a few number of setups for which this holds? I tried using the first part of the problem. i.e. if the chords above are perpendicular than $$a_1a_2+a_1'a_2'=0 \\ a_2'a_3'+a_2a_3=0 \\ a_3'a_1'' + a_1a_3=0$$

Would appreciate some guidance to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \large A_1 = e^{i \theta_1}, A_2 = e^{i \theta_2} , A_3 = e^{i \theta_3} $

Let $\large A'_1 = e^{i \theta} $

Since $A'_1 A'_2$ is perpendicular to $A_1 A_2$, then

$\large A'_2 =  e^{i (\theta_1+\theta_2 + \pi - \theta) } $

And since $A'_2 A'_3 $ is perpendicular to $A_2 A_3$ , then

$\large A'_3 = e^{ i(  \theta_2 +  \theta_3 + \pi  - \theta_1 - \theta_2 - \pi + \theta ) } = e^{i ( \theta_3 - \theta_1 + \theta) }$

And finally, since $A'_3 A''_1$ is perpendicular to $A_3 A_1$ then

$\large A''_1 = e^{ i ( \theta_1 + \theta_3 + \pi - \theta_3 + \theta_1  - \theta) }= e^{i ( 2 \theta_1 + \pi - \theta ) }$

Since we want $A''_1 $ to be coincident with $A'_1$ , then

$ 2 \theta_1 + \pi - \theta = \theta $

or

$ 2 \theta_1 + \pi - \theta = \theta + 2 \pi $

And this leads to two values for $\theta$

$ \theta = \theta_1 + \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

and

$ \theta = \theta_1 - \dfrac{\pi}{2} $